# how can I create button and picture horizontally?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to create more buttons and pictures either in horizontal or vertical direction.

[like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouNm1.png)

please help me for doing this...

Comment: this picture   http://i.stack.imgur.com/ouNm1.png

Comment: Use RecyclerView or View Pager

Comment: What you want isn't clear. Please be more specific.

Comment: pleas give me exemple code

Comment: see this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/ouNm1.png   I wnat add more button and picture horizontal or vertical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: 10 button with texte

Comment: Please add a screenshot of layout you want to achieve.

Comment: this image has only 4 controls.. two buttons and two images i guess

Answer (score 0):

Manage your layout `orientation="horizontal"` and `orientation="vertical"` you will get views in horizontal and vertical from

here some code copy paste in your XML layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Btn1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#a03"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Btn2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#a03"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="btn3" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#a03"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="btn4" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#a03"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Graphical View

[image]